# Exception in Parsing the image into the sharing intent in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, casting

I am buidong an App and want to share the image to the facebook. Following is my code which I am using to share the image to the facebook

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap iconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            iconBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            Intent sharingIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            sharingIntent1.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.encode(data.toString()) );
            sharingIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sharingIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent1, "Share Image"));
            Log.v("in sharing after");
```

But I am getting the null, and parcing exception as below :

```
> V/BitmapFactory﹕ DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
04-14 12:42:43.257  14798-14798/com.brokenfloorstudios.suitmeup W/Bundle﹕ Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected ArrayList but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
04-14 12:42:43.267  14798-14798/com.example.postfacebook W/Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList**
            at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:854)
            at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:5442)
            at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:8217)
            at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:8181)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1492)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3942)
```

**EDIT **
I have tried facebook-sdk it is 3.0(or something) Now I am successful to going into a wall post dialog and I am trying to post a picture over here along with the caption , But the never shows , Here is my code

```
params.putString("name","Selfie");
                        params.putString("caption","Selfie is really awesome");

                        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);


                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        largeIcon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);;
                        data1 = baos.toByteArray();
                        params.putByteArray("picture", data1);


                        fb.dialog(ShowCapturedImage.this,"feed",params,new Facebook.DialogListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {

                            }
                        });
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

fb.dialog is from v2 of the Facebook SDK and has been deprecated for over 2 years. It also uses a web dialog, which does not support binary image uploads.

You should follow the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), and the [Sharing guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) to use the `ShareDialog` class in the new SDK.

Comment: I have tried it by using new sdk 4.0.1 but it is not working. I have tried code from github , and sharing a small picture but there comes an error message saying your image can not be upload.

Comment: If you have any other surce code please share with me

Comment: Please post what you tried to do with 4.0, and what the exact error was. Any code I would post would already be covered by the Sharing guide I linked to above. You can also look at the sample apps that ship with the SDK (try Hello Facebook, which will post a picture).

Comment: I am trying and using the whole class that was in sample code in sdk to post a picture on the facebook. and it is working fine now, But now there is a problem and that is when I post a picture to the wall it posted with public but my friends can not see it .